# Source control in Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, azure

I am about to start using Visual Studio 2012 Pro with Azure Websites. I am not using Source control at present. However the idea of rolling back previous versions is very appealing if new code does not work. I really want to keep this as simple as possible.

The options I see are:

1.) TFS (service)

2.) GIT from Local repository to Azure Repository.

3.) Hosted GIT. SInce I am not using GIT at present, then I think this could become an unnecessary extra step.

I am using MVC3, EF4.1, SQL Server, C#.

From your experiences of both, it would be very interesting to hear of your observations

Thank you in advance.

EDIT:

Yes it could be opinion based, but I was hoping for some factual feedback from any folks that had perhaps tried both. I have altered my question above accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Visual Studio Online](http://visualstudio.com/). It integrates well with [Azure Management Portal](http://manage.windowsazure.com/) and offers both TFS and Git.

Visual Studio Online is [free for up to 5 users](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/visual-studio-online/). Whether you want to go with Git or TFS, I suggest you play around with both and then decide which one you like.

It also offers Agile and Scrum development process templates.